# Authentication with Jaydata and ASP.NET OData with Identity

Tags: asp.net, authentication, odata, asp.net-identity, jaydata

I'm trying to access my OData server using ASP.NET Identity for authentication. Is there a possibility to do that with JayData? Unfortunately, there's almost no information about that throughout the internet.

Or should one do authentication with OData and JayData with a different technology? Please consider that the server uses ASP.NET.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JayData supports basic authentication, so your JayData context can be initialized with the following parameters:

```
var yourContext = new YourContextType({
        name: "oData", 
        oDataServiceHost: '/Northwind.svc', 
        user: "user", 
        password: "password" })
```

Of course you should pass these parameters from a login form and publish your backend service over https.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, too, but when I looked in the request headers there was no such header as "Authorization". So now I found another possibility: I used prepareRequest. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476795/jaydata-js-how-to-pass-variable-to-the-request-header It's not perfect, but it's better than nothing... Thank you, anyway! :)

Comment: which datajs version do you use?

Comment: Please try to downgrade to datajs 1.0.3, the new ones seems to dropt headers by default.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now with every version - the problem was that I tried to set "password" to "" - JayData didn't like that...

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to previous datajs versions (such as 1.0.3) will resolve this issue. Newer version of datajs are removing some headers.